# Sorting arrayList in java based on user input

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following class.

```
class{
        String name;
        int marks;
};
```

Now i have to sort the objects either alphabetically(names) or descending(marks),based on user input.
How to write the comparator function for this.
User will enter 'n' to sort using names and 'm' to sort using marks.

Comment: What  have you done so far ?

Comment: Either pass the user input to the comparator or select a comparator based on user input (probably the better way to do it).

Comment: I am new to Java, and just studied ArrayList, so i'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 1):

Create two `Comparator<>` one for **names** another for **marks** and based on your user input choose one and perform following.

```
Collections.sort(yourList, yourComparator);
```

See [sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-)

```
public class YourFirstComparator implements Comparator<YourClass> {
    @Override
     public int compare(YourClass o1, YourClass o2) {
        // your logic to return 
        // -1 if o1 is small, 1 is o1 is greater, 0 if both are equals
        return  yourValue

    }
}
```

Comment: how may these comparators look like?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou see the updated answer

Comment: I meant, that there are `name` and `makrs` variables in OP class already, so they may be just `Comparator.comparing(e -> e.name)` and `Comparator.comparing(e -> -e.marks)`

Comment: See some example here https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/